# libpq send integer as binary

Tags: c, postgresql, binary, integer, libpq

I have a libpq program that is routinely inserting numbers into a database. These numbers, which I'm expecting to grow quite large, are stored int the uint64_t type. I'm wanting to send the integer to libpq as binary, but Postgres won't be able to tell its unsigned. Is there a way to specify an unsigned integer in Postgres or libpq?

Comment: When you say you're expecting them to grow "quite large" - genuinely over (2^63)-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no unsigned datatypes in PostgreSQL.

If you really are going over 9223372036854775808, then you should use NUMERIC data type.